# Where to get the Slic3r configuration files for the 3D PrinterWorks Creatorbot printers?

Tags: slic3r, 3d-printerworks

I have a Creatorbot 3D printer made by 3D PrinterWorks.  Their website appears to be down, as well as their Facebook page. To me it appears they are no longer around.

I've installed Slic3r as 3D PrinterWorks has recommended in the handbook but cannot download the settings for this from the 3D PrinterWorks website, since that is down.

Does anyone know where I can get the Slic3r configuration file for the Creatorbot?

Comment: I interpret this as the slicer config is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like 3dprinterworks.net went down sometime after March 2018 and 3dprinterworks.com went down in January 2019. Luckily the Wayback Machine still has the [machine's specs](https://web.archive.org/web/20161209084908/https://www.3dprinterworks.com/products/creatorbot-3d-pro-series-ii).

Here is the instructions for entering settings in Slic3r as found [here](https://manual.slic3r.org/expert-mode/printer-settings) in lieu of importing a profile. (Please note that I have not used Slic3r so the following is solely based on the link)

The key settings under General are

- Bed size*: X = 305 mm; Y = 305 mm; and Z = 457 mm
- Print center**: X = 152.5 mm; Y = 152.5 mm
- Extruders: 2
- Heated Bed: Checked

Under Extruder (each extruder should have its own settings so be sure to set up both)

- Nozzle diameter: 0.4 mm
- Extruder 2 offset: 30.9 mm (good job, OP on finding the email stating this)
- Everything from Retraction and on is up to what works best for you

There may be a set of setting for acceleration (there is in Ultimaker Cura) which is 3000 mm/s<sup>2</sup> for most printers, I think. This is the max acceleration, not to be confused with acceleration settings when slicing the model.

The next set of settings, though outside of the Slic3r link, regards the filament. The diameter should be 1.75 mm and the nozzle temperature should be within the range of the filament (e.g. PLA should be set within 180-220 °C) and a heated bed set to 50-60 °C. These parameters are filament dependent and not printer dependent (other than diameter).

That should be the settings that a profile would set for you. Thankfully there's not too many.

---

```
*There is a wizard for this section that may make input easier, but here is the build volume. 
**This setting may require whole numbers and may, in fact, not be a necessary setting at all.
```

Comment: I just found in an old email from Ben Kilar, owner of the company that built the printer, the 2nd extruder offset.  It's 30.9 mm.

Comment: @mbmast good job on finding that. I updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 3):

The configuration files were on a flash drive that came with the printer.  That being said, here is the file that was located on my flash drive for Slic3r (denoted as deprecated on March 1, 2017).

This is for a Creatorbot Pro II.

https://pastebin.com/j1dkSt8f

Save it as Slic3r_config.ini and import it in to Slic3r.

Good luck!